# modify every object in json array in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

Json Array - [{"a":1},{"a":2}]

Is there a way that I can update/set each object in this array with a single query ?.

I can update an specific object using `

```
SELECT JSON_SET('[{"a":1},{"a":2}]','$[0].b','new val')
```

which results

```
[{"a": 1, "b": "new val"}, {"a": 2}]
```

But I need

```
[{"a": 1, "b": "new val"}, {"a": 2, "b": "new val"}]
```

. I use mysql 8.0.22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple "a" then make first a JSON table and then combine it back.

With miore complicate and nested json y ou must do more work on the JSON_TABLE

> ```
> SELECT JSON_SET('[{"a":1},{"a":2}]','$[0].b','new val');
> ```
>
> ```
> | JSON_SET('[{"a":1},{"a":2}]','$[0].b','new val') |
> | :----------------------------------------------- |
> | [{"a": 1, "b": "new val"}, {"a": 2}]             |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>  JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT("a", a, "b", "new valuze")) 
>      FROM
>        JSON_TABLE(
>          '[{"a":1},{"a":2}]',
>          "$[*]" COLUMNS(
>            a VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.a"
>          )
>        ) AS  jt1;
> ```
>
> ```
> | JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT("a", a, "b", "new valuze"))          |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | [{"a": "1", "b": "new valuze"}, {"a": "2", "b": "new valuze"}] |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a98b8cf34e8faf63f758d7db3b2518d0)*

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I tested:

```
mysql> set @j='[{"a":1},{"a":2}]';

mysql> with recursive cte as (
    select 0 as i, json_set(@j, '$[0].b', 'new val') as j 
    union all 
    select cte.i+1, json_set(cte.j, concat('$[',cte.i+1,'].b'), 'new val') 
    from cte 
    where cte.i<json_length(@j)-1
  ) select * from cte
    where i = json_length(@j)-1;
+------+------------------------------------------------------+
| i    | j                                                    |
+------+------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | [{"a": 1, "b": "new val"}, {"a": 2, "b": "new val"}] |
+------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have to say this begs the question whether JSON is worth it. It would be far easier if you used normal rows and columns instead of JSON.